# Validate Name Surname <email@example.com> using regex in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering how I could validate a full email address with first name (optionally a last name or several last names as well) and an email address.

E.g. John Doe <john@doe.org> or Jane <jane@doe.org> should both validate correctly, where as missing name would not, e.g. <jane@doe.org>.

I'm using Django so a Python regex would do, I did not find any such validators built into Django...

Thanks!

EDIT:
To expand on the problem, how can I make this:

```
regex=re.compile('^(?P<name>[\w ]+)<(?P<email>[^ ]+@[^.]+\.[\w.]+)>$', re.UNICODE)

regex.match('José Peréz <jose.perez@example.com>')
```

match?? The re.UNICODE does not do the trick. The above only matches for 'Jose Perez '

Comment: So... you want to validate that the name is or isn't part of the e-mail address? Or do you want to validate the two separately? I can't see what e-mail has to do with this question...

Comment: I want to validate that the email part (that must be enclosed in <>) is prefixed by at least a non-empty string. Hence, two validations must take place: 1) the string is in the form: something1 <something2> 2) something2 is a valid email. Hope that clarifies it. Cheers

Comment: Minitech, the emails got lost because of using &lt;&gt; characters so the message looked really unclear, I reedited the main text. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, okay. Should have looked at it, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the first/last name is not known ahead of time so I will not try to do a regex group match (Matching the name provided and the characters before the @ symbol in the email to be equal).

```
>>> import re
>>> name_email_matcher = re.compile('^(?P<name>[A-Za-z ]+)<(?P<email>[^ ]+@[^.]+\.[\w.]+)>$')
>>> inp = 'John <john@doe.org>'
>>> inp2 = '<jane@doe.org>'
>>> print (name_email_matcher.match(inp) is not None)
True
>>> print (name_email_matcher.match(inp2) is not None)
False
```

Modify the character class for the name to accept more than just alphabets and spaces. Similarly for the email, I have designed the classes based on your question.

You can extract the name/email as well with the same regex by:

```
>>> match = name_email_matcher.search(inp)
>>> if match is not None:
...     print match.group('name')
...     print match.group('email')
John
john@doe.org
```

Comment: Thanks live2bshiv! That does the trick, just one thing I need to improve, unicode character matching. Since many languages contain special chars and often in the name, I need to allow that as well. I've been trying this one:
re.compile('^(?P<name>[^\W\d_\s]+)<(?P<email>[^ ]+@[^.]+\.[\w.]+)>+$', re.UNICODE) but it's not giving me what I want, I think I am missing correct space allocation...Any idea?

Comment: @Rok: When it comes to regexes, clear examples like the ones in the question really help. Looking at "(?P<name>[^\W\d_\s]+)", you seem to say that a name should NOT contain spaces (Eg. "John Doe"). This regex will fail because you ignore the space between the name and the "<email>".

Comment: It's not that I don't want to google for stuff :) But after spending 45mins trying to find how to mix inclusion and exclusion in a single [] condition, I'm giving up. Does anyone know how I can write this condition [^\W]+ that would also allow spaces?

Comment: Isn't [^\W]+ the same as [\w ]+ ? You are basically saying capturing everything that is NOT a non-word character.